# How to create multi-slug admin page and retrieve it with $_GET or something?

Tags: plugins, slug

So, I have seen many plugins use multi-slug to check updates and retrieve it. E.g. it have a button which redirects `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` which is equal to `admin.php?page=ani-plugin-welcome` to `admin.php?page=ani-plugin-welcome&check_for_update=true`.

and I think something like if statement with isset() and $_GET it retrieves updates (maybe with json file available in web) then it states that update is available.

By default `add_menu_page or add_submenu_page` doesn't have any multi-slug option and retrieving $_GET option. So how we will make double slug and check for it that it is isset and true or not.

The main problem I face is I cannot retrieve $_GET as i'm not making slug from admin.php, instead I'm making it from my own plugin.

I'm intermediate in wordpress (neither new nor professional).

Note: sorry for bad english

Comment: when you are on the page content, you can read `$_GET` to know what the page must dispaly. edit your question to add the code that doesn't work as you want.

Comment: actually code is too big would i post?? superglobal $_GET doesn't retrive param uri... It is not accessable!! any other suggestion